# I was genereate many times the apk and his don't have a previously code changes but in emulator android, iOS an iOS fiscal device the changes show it

Tags: android, react-native, caching

"I was genereate many times the apk and his don't have a previously code changes but in emulator android, iOS an iOS fiscal device the changes show it. I don't know what is wrong... it seems with the native code... I did a invalidate cache, rebuild and clean proyect. I reinstalled android studio and I have still the same problem... I removed the build folder /android and /android/app too"

Comment: I'm simply finding it difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As @DrSatan1 mentioned, it's difficult to understand the question that you posted... presumably it was machine translated from another language. Are you able to have a friend that writes English help out with the translation to English? If not, maybe you can also post the question in your native language and we can try to use different MT engines to understand what you're asking (not ideal, but I've seen this work).